# Own HTML page editor - own language / processing own tags?

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg

I need to create WYSIWYG editor meant for creation a modification HTML pages with advanced functions.

I have an idea that I have a HTML page and in it ssource I will use own tags - these tags allow user to modify concrete block (e.g. set article content, format it) or set source for image etc. Some tags allow to repeat the block, define if block is editable, moveable. The editor allow to create new tags also.

Editor parses HTML source, higlight for user all editable blocks and for all these blocks enable modification. The editor probably will by written in JS.

This is only my idea, many questions remain. Maybe exists some JS library that makes this task easier. Does anybody have an experience with some similar task? Please share your your experiences.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a rather complex task.
So i'm trying to give you some ideas, what features may be useful.

First of all, i assume with the custom tags you meant kind of a template, that defines the entry point of the editor and defines which elements are editable and which not.
To parse this template, you have to options([source](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp)):

- If you load the template from a remote source, use XMLHttpRequests:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","books.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

- If it is already available as a string, use the DOM-Parser

```js
var parser=new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(TheVariableContainingTheXML,"text/xml");
```

Please note that these only work with newer browsers, for older ones, take a look at the source mentioned above.
After that, the xmlDoc variable can be used as XMLDocument([reference](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_document.asp)).
Use that to initialize the editor.

Now: Moving around objects.

Basically you can use the HTML5 drag and drop API([turorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp),[events](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)). If you're familiar with some GUI-Editors(like the ones in NetBeans, Xcode or even other software like iWork) you know that many of those provide help lines. To realize that you should use a transparent [HTML 5 canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp) and snap the moved item to those lines(be creative).

And: Editing texts.

This can be utilized quite simple: styled textareas.
Maybe you could add some styles to the text area to hide the borders.
If you want to provide formatting, you could use DIV-Elements that create text areas if they are clicked.

If you want to edit images, you should think about a suitable backend.
I have not yet worked on something like this, but here, have some ideas:

- The drag and drop api supports files and checking file types, a canvas could display the image
- Or you could use the old school file inputs and IMG-Elements to upload and display images

I hope that this will help you with your project.